# How to reinstall a legacy DB2 Server 7.x for Linux?

Tags: db2, linux

We have to move our legacy database dump to a new Linux installation. I know DB2 7.x is out of support for over a decade, but is there a way to obtain a DB2 7.x Server installation media for Linux? Barring that, what other options do we have?

Comment: Try contacting IBM Software Support if you are entitled to support. If not, your best bet is to migrate to a modern version of DB2 Express-C.

Answer (score 2):

DB2 certification guides, like [this one on Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0130913669), often contain CDs with trial versions of the DB2 server. If you can get hold of one, install it on a fittingly ancient operating system, and roll back the clock to before the trial expiration threshold, you might have a shot at restoring your old backup.