# Where can I get the installation software for Oracle 8i DB?

Tags: oracle, oracle-8i

I have some backup files for an old Oracle 8i data that was created years ago. I need to be able to view this data and export it to a csv file.

The backup directory includes .dbf, .ctl , .arc and a few other file formats.

My initial thought is to obtain an installation of this DB so I can try to restore it. Is there anyway I can obtain it? (Any OS would be fine)

Any suggestions on how to do this would be great.

Comment: You can only get that from Oracle if you have a support contract (and a really expensive one that is)

Comment: See if [this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/93995/how-to-reinstall-a-legacy-db2-server-7-x-for-linux/218541#218541) gives you an idea.

Comment: Are you sure those are backup files and no the actual datafiles? If I was you I would try (linux) strings on them or open them in (MS) Notepad. As long as they are not encrypted you should be able to read them.

Comment: Amazon has books with pocket cds for Windows NT and Redhat Linux. Here is the link for [Windows NT](https://www.amazon.com/Oracle8I-Windows-Starter-Oracle-Press/dp/007212248X/ref=sr_1_8?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1544123913&sr=1-8) and [Linux](https://www.amazon.com/Oracle8i-Linux-Starter-CD-ROM-Package/dp/0072124423)

Comment: @sam Thanks so much we will try to order this.

Comment: @Munchi I think you might be right. But when I try to look into these files I'm not able to see the data as something I can make sense out of. Any way you know how I can turn this data to csv?

Comment: Oracle Support Document 1071023.1 (Requesting Physical Shipment or Download URL for Software Media), https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/ui/km/DocumentDisplay.jspx?id=1071023.1%20

Answer (score 1):

If you have 9i or 10g, you can try starting the database with either of those provided you do a startup upgrade. You should then do a manual upgrade. Of course you need to make sure that the endian is the same, and ideally the same type. ie. Linux/Windows/Unix.